# Dataflow resource usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iot

After following the dataflow tutorial, I used the pub/sub topic to big query template to parse a JSON record into a table.  The Job has been streaming for 21 days.  During that time I have ingested about 5000 JSON records, containing 4 fields (around 250 bytes).

After the bill came this month I started to look into resource usage.  I have used 2,017.52 vCPU hr, memory 7,565.825 GB hr, Total HDD  620,407.918 GB hr.

This seems absurdly high for the tiny amount of data I have been ingesting.  Is there a minimum amount of data I should have before using dataflow?  It seems over powered for small cases.  Is there another preferred method for ingesting data from a pub sub topic?  Is there a different configuration when setting up a Dataflow Job that uses less resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the numbers you mentioned, correspond to not customizing the job resources. [By default streaming jobs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pricing) use a n1-standar-4 machine:

> 3 Streaming worker defaults: 4 vCPU, 15 GB memory, 400 GB Persistent Disk.
> 4 vCPU x 24 hrs x 21 days = 2,016
> 15 GB x 24 hrs x 21 days = 7,560

If you really need streaming in Dataflow, you will need to pay for resources allocated even if there is nothing to process.

**Options:**

***Optimizing Dataflow***

- Considering that the number and size of the JSON string you need to process are really small, you can reduce the cost to aprox 1/4 of current charge. You just need to set the job to use a [n1-standard-1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/general-purpose-machines#n1_machines) machine, which has 1vCPU and 3.75GB memory. Just be careful with max nodes, unless you are planning increase the load, one node may be enough.

***Your own way***

- If you don't really need streaming (not likely), you can just create a function that pulls using [Synchronous Pull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#synchronous_pull), and add the part that writes to BigQuery. You can schedule according to your needs.

***Cloud functions*** (my recommendation)

- You can create a serverless [Event-Driven Cloud Function with a Cloud Pub/Sub trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub). This way, considering your low volume, you can take advantage of the Free Tier and keep the real time processing:

"Cloud Functions provides a perpetual free tier for compute-time resources, which includes an allocation of both GB-seconds and GHz-seconds. In addition to the 2 million invocations, the free tier provides 400,000 GB-seconds, 200,000 GHz-seconds of compute time and 5GB of Internet egress traffic per month."[1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing

Comment: Thank you for the info.